# Sizing and positioning elements based on window width

Tags: css, positioning

I have kind of a weird question. On my page I have a main image of a planet in some heavy duty nebula.  I have it set up so the min width is 1000px and max is 1500px. I have the sides fading out and this looks great with larger screens. What I'd like to try to do is when you're looking at it on a mobile device for example and it's cutting off the width at 1000 pixels, I'd like the image say 1300 pixels wide, centered and 150 pixels is cut off each side so you can't see the fade out at all, but is still able to then enlarge is the window's width becomes larger say on like a large iMac and that fade then becomes visible again once you pass that 1300 pixel width.

My initial thought was to do something with negative margins on either side, but I couldn't get this to work while keeping the max and mix widths.

This is that specific section of code from the page, though the html and css is right there for everyone to see, you can just use the fine command to find that div ID for any further looking.

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;">
   <div id="help" style="
      position:relative;
      z-index:1;
      height:100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      max-width: 1500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
   ">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFshX.jpg" border="0" style="width:100%;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on this, it's very close to working the way I'd like it to, just needs a small tweak.

Comment: what if you put the image as the background of the div and make its background-position to center?

Comment: Sounds like you need a responsive web design: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/ Using these techniques, you can create custom css rules that target just mobile sized screens.

Comment: +1 - nice site, and tricky question

Comment: haha thanks, glad you like the site, after this it's just a matter of implementing content.  About doing it as a background, I'm not sure how this would change anything as it's still the div that's re sizing.  I guess the question is, can you prompt a change in css based on window width?

Comment: awesome site,i never saw image as good/better as in your website amazing 3d looking website i really appreciate your website

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer How do you log in?

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer Right here. That username seems somewhat difficult to type.

Comment: you mean this _N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer_ it aint my user name :D

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer I see. Interesting screen name anyway.

Answer (score 163):

**Viewport units for CSS**

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
```

This way, you don't have to write many different media queries or javascript.

**If you prefer JS**

```
window.innerWidth;
window.innerHeight;
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uCA5F/show/)

Here is an actual implementation of what you described. I rewrote your code a bit using the latest best practices to actualize is. If you resize your browser windows under `1000px`, the image's left and right side will be cropped using negative margins and it will be `300px` narrower.

```
<style>
   .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
   }

   .bg {
      position:relative;
      z-index: 1;
      height: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      max-width: 1500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .nebula {
      width: 100%;
   }

   @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      .nebula {
         width: 100%;
         overflow: hidden;
         margin: 0 -150px 0 -150px;
      }
   }
</style>

<div class="container">
   <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFshX.jpg" class="nebula">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try absolute positioning:

```html
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;">
    <div id="help" style="
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;">
        <img src="/portfolio/space_1_header.png" border="0" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm so that works in terms of fitting into a screen of 1000 pixels wide.  But is it possible to have the image so when it's a window of 1000 pixels or less have the overflow be hidden, but not just on one side, on both sides equally, but still keep the ability to have a max width of 1500 pixels?

Comment: @loriensleafs, i'm not sure what you mean by that, but you could just use `margin: 0 auto` to position the image in the horizontal center, so both sides will get equal side margins on any window width. or, better yet, post a *new question* describing your specific case.

Answer (score 6):

A good trick is to use inner box-shadow, and let it do all the fading for you rather than applying it to the image.

Comment: does that work with webkit-mask?  Good idea for the masking, could work well with kingjeffrey's idea up above for the div re sizing part.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy trick would be to set a max-width and set the width at 100%:

```
.container{
max-width: 1500px; //(max of your screen/big screen)
width: 100%; // important for responsive;
overflow: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
}

div {
    margin: auto;
}
```

This will center align objects and then also center align the items within them to center align multiple objects with different widths.

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvZy8.png)